# SQLAlchemy Relationships

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, relationship

I understand that `ForeignKey` constrains a column to be an id value contained in another table so that entries in two different tables can be easily linked, but I do not understand the behavior of `relationships()`. As far as I can tell, the primary effect of declaring a relationship between `Parent` and `Child` classes is that `parentobject.child` will now reference the entries linked to the parentobject in the children table. What other effects does declaring a relationship have? How does declaring a relationship change the behavior of the SQL database or how SQLAlchemy interacts with the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything at the database level, it's purely for convenience.  Defining a `relationship` lets SQLAlchemy know how to automatically query for the related object, rather than you having to manually use the foreign key.  SQLAlchemy will also do other high level management such as allowing assignment of objects and cascading changes.